# Angular 2 HTTP, how to handle server response?

Tags: angular

I am trying to get my auth service and login component to play nice. But it doesnt seem to be working. Essentially, on login my server return either {user: user} or {error: errorMessage}.

For obvious reasons, I dont want to parse the response in my component, I need it to return a user or an error string. The success, seems to be working great, I log in, and the User is returned to the login component, but on error, for some reason, the entire Response object is returned to the login component. Which I then need to parse. Show me what I am doing wrong. Thanks !

Login function in the AuthService Class

```
  login(UserLogin): Observable<any> {
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('action', 'login');
    params.set('username', UserLogin.username);
    params.set('password', UserLogin.password);

    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl, {search: params, withCredentials: true})
    .map(
      response => response.json().user as User,
      response => Observable.throw(response.json().error)
    )
  }
```

And this is the login function in the LoginComponent Class

```
  onSubmit() {
    this.authService.login(this.user)
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log('login success', response);
        this.activeModal.close();
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      }, response => {
        console.log('login error', response);
        this.errorMessage = response.json().error; <= HERE!!!
      });
  }
```

I need to parse the response again to get the error. This doesnt seem right. I feel like im missing something.

Comment: For clarification, I also tried map(
      response => response.json().user as User,
      response => response.json().error
    )

Comment: You should go for `cath` operator in rxjs in order to handle errors. In map function just handle successful response and in catch handle error response and remember catch will only execute when status of your response is one of 401, 503 etc otherwise you can simply map your response and go on err callback never executed